# I need help interpreting char arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, char

If I were given a character array with a maximum length of say 1000 that will always follow the guidelines `int,int,char,int` for example `"12,6,@,3"` What is the easiest way to separate them and store them to their respective variable type. I know their is such things as `isdigit` and such but its really daunting to think of how many nested `if`'s I would need to interpret these `char`s not knowing how many characters each `int` could be. I'm very new to programming so please don't be rude I'm just looking for help.

Comment: If the string has comma-delimited values, use [strtok](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) to parse.

Comment: Do you want to also detect if the input string is invalid?

Answer (score 2):

If the input format is fixed like that, you can use `sscanf`:

```
char inp[] = "12,6,@,3";
int a, b, d;
char c;
if (sscanf(inp, "%d,%d,%c,%d", &a, &b, &c, &d) == 4) {
    printf("Received: %d %d %c %d", a, b, c, d);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ljA6Pe)

Comment: This was incredibly helpful thank you, will this function sscanf work with other specifiers as well? such as "intxint" for example 12x32?

Comment: @AaronJamesRasmussen Absolutely, it will work with all specifiers accepted by scanf functions described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf).

Comment: If you don't mind I have a semi unrelated question. If I want to open a file that has a name specified by the user. What is a good way to do so? So for example I have 
int boolean1 = 0;
    while(boolean1 == 0)
    {
        tempChar = getchar();
        if(tempChar == EOF)
            break;
        else
            artName[counter] = tempChar;
        counter++;
    }
artName being the name of the file. So if that works fine how do I get it to open that file? So far I have FILE * fpointer; fpointer = fopen("artName", "r"); I'd like to apologize for this sloppy input.

Answer (score 2):

If you are really sure of your input, you could just use sscanf():

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    typedef struct Ds {
        int i1;
        int i2;
        char c1;
        int i3;
    } Ds;
    Ds ds; 
    sscanf("12,6,@,3","%d,%d,%c,%d",&ds.i1, &ds.i2, &ds.c1, &ds.i3);
    printf("%d,%d,%c,%d\n",ds.i1,ds.i2,ds.c1,ds.i3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A local `typedef`, are you sure?

Comment: @alk: It's legal.  Whether it's really useful is a separate matter.  I'd probably not use a typedef and if I used a structure, would simply define the structure type and the variable of that type.  OTOH, when I do that, the variable is normally an array of the structure type and is initialized with some data — usually for some sort of test case where the type isn't needed anywhere else.